# Search inside arrays, count, find duplicates, compare

Tags: php, arrays, count, multidimensional-array, compare

Several **HOW TO** questions about simple and multidimensional arrays:

**1) How to search in simple and multi arrays?**

**2) How to count number of search results?**

**3) How to catch duplicates inside:**

```
 3.1 multidimensional array?

 3.2 simple array?

 3.3 in array's search results?

 3.4 and remove them?
```

**4) How to compare two arrays (multidimensional also?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To search if a value exists in simple array, simply use `in_array`, to get value's key, use `array_search`. For multidimensional arrays write a recursive function, that will search for values, and recurse if a value is an array (sub array).
2. Let the above function return total found, and sum all sub recursions return values.
3. To catch duplicates in:

   1. Multidimensional arrays: a recursive function with the same concept of the above
   2. Simple arrays: keys won't duplicate for sure, and use `array_unique` to remove duplicates (you can check the array length before and after to see if anything got removed, which means a duplicate was found).
   3. the search results should be a simple array, pass it to the above one.
   4. to remove them; `array_unique` as stated above.
4. to compare arrays: `array_ intersect` and `array_ diff`, for multidimensional use those functions user-callback variation to achieve what you want.

Also have a look at [PHP Array Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Answer (score 2):

To remove duplicates try this: [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Count number of search results:

```
$values = array_count_values($array); 
$count = $values[$value]; //$value is what you search for
```

Answer (score 1):

**Search:** [array_search](https://www.php.net/array_search)

**Duplicates:** [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

**Compare:** [array_diff](https://www.php.net/array_diff) OR [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

As for their multidimensional counterparts - just scroll through the user comments on the bottom on each functions page, you'll be sure to find a nice function thats been contributed by someone.

To the number of keys in an array, you can simply use the `count()` function, as it accepts arrays. So, to count your search results, you can do the following:

```
count(array_search("1", $array)); //1 being the needle and $array the haystack
```